# Django signal only works when debug=True, DJANGO 3.2.4

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I've been looking everywhere and I coulnd't find any reference about this, my Django model signal only works when the debug=True, but it doesn't work if debug=False, this occur both on localhost and production server.

My settings looks like this:

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import environ

env = environ.Env()

environ.Env.read_env()

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

#production
STATIC_ROOT = 'https://d1u356tnw52tcs.cloudfront.net/'


SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY_PROD")

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
)


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'sellrapp',
    'stock_management',
    'corsheaders',
    'drf_yasg',
    'optimized_image',
    'csvexport',
    'kronos',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = '****.urls'


WSGI_APPLICATION = '****.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': env("NAME_PROD"),
        'USER': env("USER_PROD"),
        'PASSWORD': env("PASSWORD_PROD"),
        'HOST': env("HOST_PROD"),
        'PORT': env("PORT_PROD"),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Singapore'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


WEB_BASE_URL = 'https://****.com/'
BASE_URL_LIVE_CAMPAIGN = WEB_BASE_URL + "product/"
```

if set to debug=False, the signal wouldn't triggered, and there's no any error trown.

signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save, pre_delete
from .models import ManualWithdrawals


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=ManualWithdrawals)
def manual_wd(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    order = ManualWithdrawals.objects.get(id=instance.id)
    consumer_order = order.order_id_list.all()
    sample_order = order.sample_order_id_list.all()
    total = str(instance.total_withdrawals).replace(".", "")
    total = int(total)
    if instance.order_id_list:
        for order in consumer_order:
            if instance.type == "reseller" and order.reseller_commission_status != "paid":
                order.reseller_commission_status = "ready for collection"
                order.save()
            if instance.type == "merchant" and order.merchant_commission_status != "paid":
                order.merchant_commission_status = "ready for collection"
                order.save()
        # updating sample order if any
    if instance.sample_order_id_list:
        for order in sample_order:
            if instance.type == "merchant" and order.merchant_commission_status != "paid":
                order.merchant_commission_status = "ready for collection"
                order.save()
```

Comment: Can you try any other signals like pre_save just to see if it is working so that we can confirm it is a project-level issue and not specific to this signal?

Comment: pre_save and all method is also not working... is it possible because I'm using https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/# ? @cmkishores

Comment: Facing the same issue. Has anyone found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out that the problem happening when I'm updating to a new version of `psycopg`, somehow after updating my `psycopg` to the latest version now it's working just fine.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Sorry but updating to latest version of psycopg does not work for me

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

Pass weak=False when you call the signal’s `connect()` or `@receiver`.

---

[Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/) mention warning that:

> Note also that Django stores signal handlers as weak references by default, so if your handler is a local function, it may be garbage collected. To prevent this, pass weak=False when you call the signal’s connect().

Thus, it is possible that your receiver function is getting garbage-collected.

For example, try using: `@receiver(pre_delete, sender=ManualWithdrawals, weak=False)`

Answer (score 5):

Just to add more insights to @kaustubh-trivei answer.

When handler is registered this way:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_and_register_handler(model):
    def handler(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
        ...

    post_save.connect(handler, sender=model)
```

then `weak=False` is manadatory, otherwise it gets garbage collected and unregistered immediately.

Due to implementation detail, when `settings.DEBUG` is `True`, Django creates one extra reference to the handler, which prevents the handler from being garbage collected and unregistered.

Implementation detail: when `settings.DEBUG` is `True`, handler's arguments get validated by `django.utils.inspect` module, which uses `functools.lru_cache()` decorator internally, which leads to the handler being stored as a key in lru cache dict.

Answer (score 2):

We got the same error, it's because of using the same function name for 2 signals.

```
@reciever(....)
def set_something(...):
    pass

@reciever(...)
def set_something(...): # This function name is the same as above
    pass
```