# django signal post_save is not working while debug is false

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I've implemented django signals for a model. It's only working fine while debug is True. Any idea how to fix this issue, so that post_save signal works when debug is False in production.

Here is my code in models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=PackageSubscription)
def update_balance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    current_balance = Balance.objects.get(user=instance.user)
    last_balance = current_balance.last_balance
    get_package = Package.objects.filter(title=instance.package)
    for i in get_package:
        get_coin = i.coin
    update_current_balance = last_balance + get_coin

    if instance.payment_status is True:
       Balance.objects.filter(user=instance.user).update(last_balance=update_current_balance, updated_at=timezone.now())
```

FYI - I'm using django 3.2.4

Comment: check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69003196/django-signal-only-works-when-debug-true-django-3-2-4

Comment: Thanks @Jisson for your recommendation link, as per the post I've upgraded psycopg2-binary version but nothing changed. Still the same error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69630143/10588679

Comment: have you found anything? @Mehady

Comment: yes, user weak=False and that works perfectly. I've used in this line: @receiver(post_save, sender=PackageSubscription, weak=False)
Let me know if you need any help.